# How to get JWT token in header when using Rails and React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, jwt, token

I've my Sessions controller set up as below. I'm looking for a way to grab the auth_token from command.result in the authenticate method and make it available in my headers when the user logs in so I can access it inside react to authenticate users on each request.

When I make a request to the authenticate action, I get the right response with the auth_token but can't figure out how to send this response to the header and use it there.

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_request
  include CurrentUserConcern

  def authenticate
    command = AuthenticateUser.call(params[:email], params[:password])

    if command.success?
      render json: { auth_token: command.result, message: 'Login successful' }
    else
      render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      .try(:authenticate, params[:password])

    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      render json: {
        status: :created,
        logged_in: true,
        user: user,
      }

    else
      render json: {
        status: 400,

      }, status: 400
    end
  end

  def logged_in
    if @current_user
      render json: {
        logged_in: true,
        user: @current_user
      }
    else
      render json: {
        logged_in: false
      }
    end
  end

  def logout
    reset_session
    render json: { status: 200, logged_out: true }
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I set a before_action in my controller to set the @token variable. This way I can use @token in any action within the controller.

```
 class Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_action :authenticate_request
      before_action :set_token
 end
```

Then I created a private method to set the token.

```
  def set_token
    command = AuthenticateUser.call(params[:email], params[:password])
    if command.success?
      @token = command.result
    else
      nil  
    end
  end
```

And called the @token variable inside my create action passing it to set_headers.

```
response.set_header('token', @token)
```